# Mutual dependence of libc6 and libgcc1

Tags: debian, apt, dependencies

I found that the two packages `libgcc1` and `libc6` depend on each other (in `debian 10`), so none can exist without the other.
Why is that? Shouldn't a package depend on another and not finally on its own…?

```bash
$ LC_ALL=C apt depends libgcc1 libc6
libgcc1
  Depends: gcc-8-base (= 8.3.0-6)
  Depends: libc6 (>= 2.14)
  Breaks: <gcc-4.3> (<< 4.3.6-1)
  Breaks: <gcc-4.4> (<< 4.4.6-4)
  Breaks: <gcc-4.5> (<< 4.5.3-2)
libc6
  Depends: libgcc1
  Conflicts: openrc (<< 0.27-2~)
  Breaks: <hurd> (<< 1:0.5.git20140203-1)
  Breaks: <libtirpc1> (<< 0.2.3)
  Breaks: locales (<< 2.28)
  Breaks: locales-all (<< 2.28)
  Breaks: nocache (<< 1.1-1~)
  Breaks: nscd (<< 2.28)
  Breaks: r-cran-later (<< 0.7.5+dfsg-2)
  Recommends: libidn2-0 (>= 2.0.5~)
  Suggests: glibc-doc
 |Suggests: debconf
  Suggests: <debconf-2.0>
    cdebconf
    debconf
  Suggests: libc-l10n
  Suggests: locales
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From a package manager standpoint, there are several sorts of *dependencies*.

Firsts come the **BUILD** dependencies : Whatever packages needed to unpack, patch, compile, test or install the package.
If Pack-D is a build dependency of Pack-foo then an operational occurrence of Pack-D is needed at Pack-foo build time. (v.g. not at Pack-foo run time).
With this sort of dependency, there is (in general) no fear of the frightening *circular dependency* you think about. Pack-D may without any trouble need Pack-foo at build time. Think for example of gcc as a build dependency of some zipper and the zipper itself being a build dependency of gcc because your package manager relies on some zipped distribution of gcc.

Seconds are **RUN TIME** dependencies. Whatever packages needed for the package to run. Language interpreters, data files of course but more generally : libraries that are needed for the link phase to proceed correctly.
In these particular cases, you are correct feeling that if lib-A is a run time dependency of lib-B then lib-B should not in turn be a run time dependency of lib-A since this would create a circular dependency to be avoided in any case.

ldd or lddtree ar nice tools to get the knowledge of these dependencies. On my system, lddtree would tell that the libc6 is actually a run time dependency of the libgcc1

```
# lddtree /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/9.4.0/libgcc_s.so.1
libgcc_s.so.1 (interpreter => None)
    libc.so.6 => /lib64/libc.so.6
        ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 => /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
```

But that libgcc1 is not a run time dependency of libc6 :

```
# lddtree /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/9.4.0/lib64/libc.so.6 
/lib64/libc.so.6 (interpreter => /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2)
    ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 => /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
```

No circular dependency in there, **nothing to worry about then**.

Thirds are **BLOCKERS** : Some package managers (gentoo portage for instance) trick the dependencies declarations to specify packages that should or not coexist in a system. Of course these does not constitute circular dependencies.